# AddLink and SetLink in DataServiceContext

Tags: wcf-data-services

I'm newby at ADO.NET Data Services. I'm just trying to understand how to work with it.

I'd like to set the link between two existing objects city and incomingCity:

IncomingCity and City has many-to-one relationship:
City has property Collection IncomingCity
IncomingCity has the only one related City -- the property is City City

The operations i do:

```
var entities = new referenceEntities(new Uri(url));

DataServiceQuery<IncomingCity> query = entities.IncomingCity.Expand("City");

var otherCities = query.Where(ic => ic.City == null);

var first = otherCities.FirstOrDefault();

entities.AddLink(originalCity, "IncomingCity", first);
entities.SetLink(first, "City", originalCity);

first.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

entities.UpdateObject(first);

entities.SaveChanges();
```

Such an exception occurs during SaveChanges method:

An error occurred while processing this request.

I cound not understand what's the matter. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell what error you are getting exactly? Maybe a fiddler trace will help.

Also, if you want the service, can you turn the debugging mode on in the server so that you get a detailed exception message - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik